# How to fetch substring from java string starting with the range of \n+ to \n and \n- to \n in below given string?

Tags: java, regex

Input string is as below:

```
@@ -106,12 +106,12 @@ end loop\n loop map dummm56\n \tdummy data/path/u/u_op/kl-sc45\n end loop\n-\n-loop map {$df=56,$kl=20564300,$testId=\"jk: message1 message2:48667697\",$kl3=true,$kl=true, $kl=[2],$kl=$kl1, $kl1=true, $kl1=[1],$kl14=$kl15,$kl16=$kl14}\n+##### message2:48667697\n+loop map {val56}\n \tl1 l2/l3/i3/l7_l90/l90-SC21_l90/l90-l90_l90_l90\n end loop\n-\n-loop map {val56}\n+#####kl message45:48667697\n+loop map {val34}\n \ttestcases data/testcases/path1/[ath5+path6/UC20015-SC21/UC20015-SC21\n end loop\n
```

In above string, I want to fetch all the sub-strings starting from **\n+** and ending with **\n**. Also, starting from **\n-** and ending with **\n** using Java regular expression.

Expected Output is as below:

```
blank  // here its blank as first \n- to next \n nothing is there.
loop map {$df=56,$kl=20564300,$testId=\"jk: message1 message2:48667697\",$kl3=true,$kl=true, $kl=[2],$kl=$kl1, $kl1=true, $kl1=[1],$kl14=$kl15,$kl16=$kl14} // as second \n- to next \n
##### message2:48667697 //third \n+ to next \n
loop map {val56}\n \tl1 l2/l3/i3/l7_l90/l90-SC21_l90/l90-l90_l90_l90 //fourth \n+ to next \n
blank // \n- to next \n
loop map {val56} // \n- to next \n
#####kl message45:48667697 // as \n+ to \n
loop map {val34} // as \n+ to \n
```

Actually I wanted to make two different sets, one for \n+ to \n and another for \n- to \n. As I wanted to use this for later purposes.

below is the java code I have tried with:

```
String str="Pasted above string making sure no additional string literals should come.";
Pattern p0 = Pattern.compile("^(\\\\n[+|-])(.*?)(\\\\n.*)?$"); 
Matcher m = p0.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
System.out.printf( m.group(0));// here I am expecting my output to get printed.
}
```

Can anyone help me out with the same. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried till now ?

Comment: Pattern p0 = Pattern.compile(".*\n+([^']*).*\n"); //tried with this but not helping out  in order to get the expected result.
Matcher m = p0.matcher(str);
while (m.find())
 {
   System.out.printf( m.group(0));
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the regex that might help you

`^(\\\\n[+|-])(.*)$`

`^ - Start of line`

`\\\\n - escaping \`

`^(\\\\n[+|-]) - Starting point of line followed by \n with either + or -`

`(.*?) anything can follow after that (? for non-greedy search if \n follows after that)`

`(\\\\n.*)? - Might be that \n follows (4th line in text)`

`$ - End of line. Assuming that after end of line what follows is \n-new line`

From the output that you have provided, it seems that there are other conditions also that you have forgot to mention in your question, like why `###problem statement1` is not in the output because it starts with `\n+` and ends with new line. Below is the code snippet for the same

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\\\n[+|-])(.*?)(\\\\n.*)?$"); 
    Matcher matcher = null;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            "filePath"));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, This logic is not helping out giving the desired output. i am giving the actual string for the operation.

Comment: @@ -106,12 +106,12 @@ end loop\n loop map dummm56\n \tdummy data/path/u/u_op/kl-sc45\n end loop\n-\n-loop map {$df=56,$kl=20564300,$testId=\"jk: message1 message2:48667697\",$kl3=true,$kl=true, $kl=[2],$kl=$kl1, $kl1=true, $kl1=[1],$kl14=$kl15,$kl16=$kl14}\n+##### message2:48667697\n+loop map {val56}\n \tl1 l2/l3/i3/l7_l90/l90-SC21_l90/l90-l90_l90_l90\n end loop\n-\n-loop map {val56}\n+#####kl message45:48667697\n+loop map {val34}\n \ttestcases data/testcases/path1/[ath5+path6/UC20015-SC21/UC20015-SC21\n end loop\n

Comment: String str="above dummy string";
  
 Pattern p0 = Pattern.compile("^(\\\\n[+|-])(.*)$"); 

  Matcher m = p0.matcher(str);
  System.out.println("gettign printed");
  while (m.find()) 
  
  {
   System.out.println("checking the print operation");
   System.out.printf( m.group(2));
  
  }

Comment: Have tried with that pattern as well which you mentioned i.e "^(\\\\n[+|-])(.*?)(\\\\n.*)?$"=> This also is not giving anything .

Comment: Update your question with the actual string and what have you tried because in comments it's not formatted properly:)

Comment: Hey, I have updated my question :) Can you please have a look. Any help would be appreciated:) Also, I have tried with the same reg ex which you told as a solution. But that is not helping out :(